# Extend the time the Windows service is stopped

Tags: c++, windows

I need the service to stop long enough. Approximately 5-10 minutes. Now on windows 10, my service system kills after 60 seconds without waiting for it to finish correctly. Saw a similar issue for C# using the net function RequestAdditionalTime. But I need a C++ implementation on the API.

setting the key value in the registry did not affect
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillService set to 300000

Comment: You can always see [.net implementation sources](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/src/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceBase.cs#L63) - they are using [SetServiceStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-setservicestatus) with `dwWaitHint` specified in [SERVICE_STATUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-_service_status)

Comment: Already tried using SetServiceStatus. Either it doesn't work or I have a mistake. I will experiment in this direction. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Fix the delay; nobody wants to wait 10 minutes for their computer to shut down. The 60 seconds limit is already stretching the users patience.

Comment: The service will be used as the main program on the server. I need the computer (along with the operating system) to work as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mess with global registry settings.

When stopping your service please call [`SetServiceStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-_service_status) with `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` and set `dwCheckPoint` and `dwWaitHint` to a proper value. And according to the documentation for `dwWaitHint` call `ServServiceStatus` multiple times until you are done and the service is stopped (`SetServiceStatus(h, SERVICE_STOPPED, ...)`).